# Lazy enumerator for nested array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, enumerable

Suppose I have an `Array` like this

```rb
data = [
  {
    key: val,
    important_key_1: { # call this the big hash
      key: val,
      important_key_2: [
        { # call this the small hash
          key: val,
        },
        {
          key: val,
        },
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    key: val,
    important_key_1: {
      key: val,
      important_key_2: [
        {
          key: val,
        },
        {
          key: val,
        },
      ]
    },
  },
]
```

I want to create a lazy enumerator that would return the next small hash on each `#next`, and move on to the next big hash and do the same when the first big hash reaches the end

The easy way to return all the internal hashes that I want would be something like this

```
data[:important_key_1].map do |internal_data|
  internal_data[:important_key_2]
end.flatten
```

Is there someway to do this or do I need to implement my own logic ?

Comment: it is not a hash, it is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a lazy enumerator which iterates over all the small hashes :

```
def lazy_nested_hashes(data)
  enum = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    data.each do |internal_data|
      internal_data[:important_key_1][:important_key_2].each do |small_hash|
        yielder << small_hash
      end
    end
  end
  enum.lazy
end
```

With your input data and a `val` definition :

```
@i = 0

def val
  @i += 1
end
```

It outputs :

```
puts lazy_nested_hashes(data).to_a.inspect
#=> [{:key=>3}, {:key=>4}, {:key=>7}, {:key=>8}]
puts lazy_nested_hashes(data).map { |x| x[:key] }.find { |k| k > 3 }
#=> 4
```

For the second example, the second big hash isn't considered at all (thanks to [`enum.lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-lazy))

Comment: The whole point is that I didn't want to evaluate the whole internal loop before returning a single value, your solution solved that for me, thank you very much, btw for me I removed the last enum call and chained the `.lazy` after the `end`